# Web assembly sending faulty Json body that the server cannot deserialize

Tags: post, rust, webassembly, serde, actix-web

**Problem**

Webassembly is sending a post req to an actix web server, but actix web says it cannot deserialize the json body.

In terminal (for actix web) you can see the error message of

```
Failed to deserialize Json from payload. Request path: /api
Error in response: Deserialize(Error("expected value", line: 1, column: 2))
```

And in javascript console

```
Response { url: "http://localhost:8080/api", status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", /* ... */ }
```

I have tried sending the same request using curl, and it worked. So there is clearly something wrong with the request the wasm is sending, but I'm not sure what

```bash
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \                                                                                                                         :(
  --request POST \
  --data '{"field1": "one", "field2": "two", "field3": "three"}' \
  http://localhost:8080/api
```

Here's the code sending the request (web assembly)

```rs
let _ = window
    .fetch_with_str_and_init("/api", &RequestInit::new().method("POST").headers(&headers).body(Some(&serde_wasm_bindgen::to_value(&req).unwrap())))
    .then(&ok);
```

and here's the server receiving the request

```rs
#[post("/api")]
async fn api(body: Json<Req>) -> String {
    format!("{body:?}")
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Req {
    field1: String,
    field2: String,
    field3: String,
}
```

Here's how to reproduce the issue:

[repo](https://github.com/Siriusmart/dummy-repo-for-asking-stackoverflow)

```bash
git clone https://github.com/Siriusmart/dummy-repo-for-asking-stackoverflow
```

`wasm-pack build --target web wasm` to recompile the web assembly first

then `cargo run` to start the server

visit http://localhost:8080 to see the site with wasm.

When the button is pressed, there should be output to the js console, saying that its a bad request, at the same time there will also be an error message in the actix web console.

The goal is to make it so that the wasm actually sends a good request to the server.

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example. At least, what is `req`? It looks like you're sending a JS object instead of JSON.

Comment: the repo is a minimal reproducible example but yeah u might be right im sending a js object that might be why

Comment: I didn't see the link to the repo, but the code should be fully contained in the question still.

Comment: https://github.com/Siriusmart/dummy-repo-for-asking-stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serde_wasm_bindgen` serializes `Req` to a JS object, and that is what `fetch()` gets. I think it calls `toString()` on it, resulting it `[object Object]` (not entirely sure), but this is definitely not sending JSON.

You need to serialize the data to JSON yourself, for example via `serde_json` then call [`JsValue: From<String>`](https://docs.rs/wasm-bindgen/0.2.84/src/wasm_bindgen/lib.rs.html#813-818) or by serializing it to JS object with `serde_wasm_bindgen` then calling [`JSON.stringify()`](https://docs.rs/js-sys/latest/js_sys/JSON/fn.stringify.html) on it.